# ns does not exist, com.mongodb.MongoCommandException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mongodb, mongock

Using mongock to perform the data migration but end up with below error.

## Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'fete.bird'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('mongockVersion', "4.1.14")
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.3.1.RELEASE'
    implementation "com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongock-standalone:${mongockVersion}"
    implementation "com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongodb-sync-v4-driver:${mongockVersion}"
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.1.0'
    compile project(':Data')
}
```

## Standalone approach

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongockStandalone();
    }

    private static void MongockStandalone(){
        var mongoUri =  Configuration.getMongoUri();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://127.0.1:27017/");
        MongockStandalone.builder()
                .setDriver(MongoSync4Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoClient,"FeteBird-Product"))
                         .addChangeLogsScanPackage("db.migration")
                        .buildRunner().execute();
    }
}
```

## Changelog

```
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class DbChangeLog001 {
    @ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "seedProduct", author = "San")
    public void seedProduct(MongoDatabase mongoDatabase) {
        mongoDatabase.createCollection("Product");
    }
}
```

## Error

```
02:04:52.060 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.operation - Unable to retry operation listIndexes due to error "com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 26 (NamespaceNotFound): 'ns does not exist: FeteBird-Product.mongockChangeLog' on server 127.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "ns does not exist: FeteBird-Product.mongockChangeLog", "code": 26, "codeName": "NamespaceNotFound"}"
02:04:52.061 [main] DEBUG com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase - Removing residual uniqueKeys for collection [mongockChangeLog]
02:04:52.063 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"listIndexes": "mongockChangeLog", "cursor": {}, "$db": "FeteBird-Product", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "2Ki32rm4RAacZEcl0iUR0A==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 17 to database FeteBird-Product on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:20}] to server 127.0.1:27017
02:04:52.069 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Execution of command with request id 17 failed to complete successfully in 6.26 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:20}] to server 127.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 26 (NamespaceNotFound): 'ns does not exist: FeteBird-Product.mongockChangeLog' on server 127.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "ns does not exist: FeteBird-Product.mongockChangeLog", "code": 26, "codeName": "NamespaceNotFound"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:359)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:280)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:100)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:490)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:110)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:345)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:336)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommandWithConnection(CommandOperationHelper.java:222)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListIndexesOperation$1.call(ListIndexesOperation.java:171)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListIndexesOperation$1.call(ListIndexesOperation.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:582)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListIndexesOperation.execute(ListIndexesOperation.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListIndexesOperation.execute(ListIndexesOperation.java:73)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:178)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.forEach(MongoIterableImpl.java:121)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.getResidualKeys(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:73)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.cleanResidualUniqueKeys(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:66)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.ensureIndex(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:52)
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.initialize(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:39)
    at io.changock.driver.core.driver.ConnectionDriverBase.initialize(ConnectionDriverBase.java:43)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.initializationAndValidation(MigrationExecutor.java:189)
    at io.changock.runner.core.MigrationExecutor.executeMigration(MigrationExecutor.java:61)
    at io.changock.runner.core.ChangockBase.execute(ChangockBase.java:44)
    at main.MongockStandalone(main.java:18)
    at main.main(main.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using a quite new version of MongoDB. Mongock used that field, but it's not needed anymore.

Since version **4.1.14**, this 'ns' field is not used, so you should stop seeing this issue.

You can take a look to [Mongock's documentation](https://www.mongock.io/quick-start).

Comment: I got the same issue after updating the version to 4.1.14